# How is the transfer of electron different from the formation of ionic pairs?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics

This is from an assignment question from an introductory solid state physics class. The question is as follows:

> In an ‘MX’ molecule, suppose the ‘M’ atom has an ionization potential of energy 5eV and ‘X’
> atom has an electron affinity of 4eV. What is the energy required to transfer an electron from ‘M’
> to ‘X’ when they are at a distance of 5 Å?

From my understanding of ionic bonds, the net energy required for this should simply be the difference between the ionisation energy of M and electron affinity of X. However, the right answer according to the solution manual is *I.E - E.A + U (coulomb)*. I fail to understand how the coulomb potential even comes into picture.

Answer (score 2):

The ionisation energy is the energy needed to take an electron from an **isolated** atom and remove it to infinity. Likewise the electron affinity is the energy we get when we take an **isolated** atom and bring an electron in from infinity.

So your process needs to be modelled as:

1. separate the neutral M and X to infinity (the energy for this is probably negligible)
2. ionise the isolated M atom
3. bring the electron onto the isolated X atom
4. bring the resulting M ⁺ and X ⁻ ions together to a distance of 5Å

The assuming the energy for step 1 can be ignored step 2 is the ionisation energy, step 3 is the electron affinity and step 4 is the potential energy of the ions. Add the three terms together to get the total energy change.